# SQL add tablename as field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen this done before but I can't remember where I saw it.

What I need to do is have the table name as a field in a query.

Say I have a table called users, how would I add the table name 'users' as a column.

Like:

```
 SELECT username, password, **table** as mytable FROM users
```

Comment: From where do you want this table name to be populated? In above case you can just do this - 

select username, password, 'users' as mytable from users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may look obvious, but did you consider the following?

```
SELECT username, password, 'users' as mytable FROM users
```